# C++ correct references

Tags: c++

Can someone explain what the difference is, if any, between these two lines:

```
int& i;
int &i;
```

I know these are both references and both seem to work fine. Is there a reason to use one over the other? Is there any rule saying what is the right way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the obvious:  one has a space before the '&' and the other doesn't.  In parsing, there doesn't need to be a space before or after the '&'.  So you forgot a 3rd equivalent example: `int&i;`.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no difference in meaning between these two, it is a purely stylistic matter. Just pick one and try to be consistent within a project.

I believe the examples in the language standard put the `&` symbol on the left - that's as good a reason as any to prefer one way over the other, I suppose.

---

That said, as you've written it, neither line is valid code, because you can't have an uninitialised reference. You would need something like:

```
int a = 10;
int& b = a;
```